# Outlook: apply rules to current message?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, rules

KMail has a really useful feature: you can define a series of rules which are only run when you press a keyboard shortcut, and then only on the highlighted messages. This allows me to read a message as it comes into the inbox, and then file it away with one key press.

How can I replicate this in Outlook? Possibly some VBA script triggered by a key press that runs all rules against all messages currently selected?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this, but you have to be a little tricky. The steps overview : make filing rules that look for a category, then make a button run a macro to change the messages selected to that category and then run the rules. See the full answer on this question, including the macro code...

[Quickly running Outlook rules on demand?](https://superuser.com/questions/251840/quickly-running-outlook-rules-on-demand/931818#931818)

I made my answer there a little more involved by naming the rules based on category with a prefix so they can be run specifically by the macro, but this is somewhat optional.

Answer (score 0):

How big is your folder? You can [Run rules manually](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-HA010355682.aspx#_Toc301245491), but that applies to the whole folder, but I imagine that this could be really slow if your folder has a large number of messages.

That link describes using **'Manage Rules & Alerts'** in the File tab to 'Run Rules Now'.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to run Outlook rules on selected messages. Only on folders. :-( Even using [Outlook Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb207534.aspx) in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can help yourself with an auxiliary routine like this:

```
Public Sub TestMessageRule()
    '  Routine to test Mail Handlers MessageRule()'
    '  without incoming mail messages
    '  select an existing mail before executing this routine
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objMail As Outlook.mailItem
    Dim started As Long

    For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If TypeName(objItem) = "MailItem" Then
            Set objMail = objItem

                '  add the following declaration at the header:
                '  Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long
                started = GetTickCount()
                MessageRule objMail

                ' showCheckerMail objMail.BillingInformation
                Debug.Print "elapsed " & (GetTickCount() - started) / 1000# & "s"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No and Yes. No to messages, yes to messages you move to a folder.

The basic VBA used on many sites http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/run-outlook-rules-startup/

```
Sub RunAllInboxRules()
    Dim st As Outlook.Store
    Dim myRules As Outlook.Rules
    Dim rl As Outlook.Rule
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim ruleList As String
    'On Error Resume Next

    ' get default store (where rules live)
    Set st = Application.Session.DefaultStore
    ' get rules
    Set myRules = st.GetRules

    ' iterate all the rules
    For Each rl In myRules
        ' determine if it's an Inbox rule
              If rl.RuleType = olRuleReceive And rl.IsLocalRule = True Then
            ' if so, run it
            rl.Execute ShowProgress:=True
            count = count + 1
            ruleList = ruleList & vbCrLf & rl.Name
        End If
    Next

    ' tell the user what you did
    ruleList = "These rules were executed against the Inbox: " & vbCrLf & ruleList
    MsgBox ruleList, vbInformation, "Macro: RunAllInboxRules"

    Set rl = Nothing
    Set st = Nothing
    Set myRules = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you want to run it against the folder you moved the message(s) to, rather than the Inbox, specify that folder.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864433%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Say you create a folder under the Inbox named "RunRules"

Once you move the message(s) to the folder:

```
Set fldRunRules = st.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("RunRules")

rl.Execute Folder:=fldRunRules
```