# Move selected e-mail to rule-defined folder on demand in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

I would like to configure Microsoft Outlook (2010 or newer) with a set of criteria and destination folders, such as "mail from person A has a destination of folder B".

I would then like to press a key to apply those rules to the **currently selected messages only**.

This will let me press one key when I have finished with an e-mail and it will be automatically filed away to the appropriate folder.

I have successfully achieved this with a couple of e-mail clients under Linux, but I would now like to duplicate this functionality with Outlook.

I don't think Quick Steps will work as there are over 100 rules, and I don't want to have to look up the right Quick Step to press (the idea is the rules figure this out automatically.)  Entering them in as actual rules (normally used for incoming messages) won't work as there's no way to run rules on selected messages (only on an entire folder at a time.)

There are some similar questions here but none cover my use case exactly:

- [861377](https://superuser.com/questions/861377/move-e-mails-into-specific-folder-using-keyboard-shortcut-in-outlook-2010) - Moves all messages into the same folder, I want the destination to change depending on the message (typically different senders into different folders)
- [251840](https://superuser.com/questions/251840/quickly-running-outlook-rules-on-demand) - Applies rules on all messages in a folder, I only want them applied to selected messages, and typically only one message at a time

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/344590/outlook-apply-rules-to-current-message

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to set up your incoming rules to move the e-mails to sub-folders. You reply to each e-mail and configure your Outlook to save the responses to the same folder. I have to admit this is an archaic approach as keyword search negates organizing e-mails in outdated file drawer system.

Comment: Unfortunately having incoming mail split across 100+ folders makes it too easy to miss, especially when you can't see all the folders on the screen at the same time, so I need it all coming into one inbox folder.  The keyword search isn't really practical either, because it can't answer things like "what was the last thing that anyone from department X asked me about?" or "who was that really helpful support person at vendor Y I contacted six months ago?"  For me, nothing works better than the "outdated" system.

Comment: Sorry if I offended you. I see a lot of people including myself moving emails into the wrong folder and resorting to search anyway. If you insist on using email as a crm (customer relations manager), you don't need a hundred folders... Just the most recent folders, clients, vendors, etc. You archive the rest. Another idea is to move your selected message to a processing folder, then run all your rules for that one folder (single email), and that gets moved to wherever you want. This would be a via script that is a toolbar and then a shortcut key associated with it.

Comment: One reason for having the rules move the messages is to avoid problems like accidentally moving them to the wrong folder.  I'm not using e-mail as CRM but the nature of my job means I often have to go back to look for the last time an issue came up.  I'm not saying filing e-mail like this is the best for everyone, but it works really, really well for me.  I just want the archiving process to be as fast with Outlook as it is with other mail clients.  Moving messages to an actioned folder then running rules on that folder is a nice idea though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This app - "NEO" just duplicates the functionality of Quick Steps, i.e. a toolbar button to move to a specific folder.  No rules or any smarts in the move process.